# Do I have to lock variables in Javascript when accessing them from events

Tags: javascript, events, parallel-processing, synchronization, locking

The following example code queues some data from subsequent calls to a method and sends all the queued data in one batch after a certain timeout or event like RAF:

[Live fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gxh1p14/4/)

```
let _queue;

function send(data) {     
  if (_queue) {
    _queue.push(data);
  } else {
    _queue = [ data ];
    // The timeout could also be replaced by some event like RAF etc.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        // Send all queued data as 1 batch request...
        _queue = undefined;
    }, 100);
  }
}

// Those calls actually come from "unpredictable" events like mouse clicks etc.
send('1');
window.setTimeout(send.bind(this, '2'), 50);
window.setTimeout(send.bind(this, '3'), 80);
```

Am I right in the assumption that I don't need to worry about locking of the `_queue` variable at all since JS is single threaded and it's not possible that there will ever be parallel access to it, no matter what the sources of the `send` calls are (`setTimeout`, RAF, UI events, ...)?

Comment: Do you mean *parallel* access rather than *synchronous* access?

Comment: You don't need to lock variables ;) like you said javascript run in a single thread.